# How does ADT optimize dead code for Android apps?

Tags: android, optimization, compiler-construction, dead-code

I'm developing a set of libraries for my Android apps.  But, as they grow in features, I don't want unused features & 3rd party libraries included in the various APKs.  Does the Android compiler automatically exclude classes and libraries that are not in use?  Is there an option I should enable in ADT/Eclipse?

Most apps will be fairly small, but I'd hate to include megabytes of unused code in each app.  And I'd also prefer to keep similar functionality together (networking, GUI, etc.)

So can someone point me to a page or other resource that explain how that works in Android?  Or maybe to an Android analog of C/C++ #ifdef/#endif ?

Comment: have you enabled proguard

Comment: No, but I've heard of it.  Also, just learned of DexGuard tonight (though it's a bit pricey as an Indie developer).  But, I'm just as interested in knowing *how* it's done in ADT/Eclipse currently, as in tools available to improve on that.  Does ADT/Eclipse do such optimizations at all?  When I tried looking through the generated APK, I wasn't really sure.

Comment: Then read this http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at that more!